In karate i'm doing deep compare but it is using too much heap space because of this VM is crashing
I am doing the deep comparision in karate while matching the responses but when the responses does not matches it take too much heap space to compare which results in VM crash.
the specific error which comes is:
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  03:29 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-04-03T11:48:30+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project Hotels-API-Guardian: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd /opt/jenkins/workspace/HOTELS-TA-JDK19-Github && /opt/java/openjdk/bin/java -jar /opt/jenkins/workspace/HOTELS-TA-JDK19-Github/target/surefire/surefirebooter2363923029464916214.jar /opt/jenkins/workspace/HOTELS-TA-JDK19-Github/target/surefire/surefire368058004839570379tmp /opt/jenkins/workspace/HOTELS-TA-JDK19-Github/target/surefire/surefire_04507318838578109367tmp

I tried to increase the heap space to 12GB but it is still giving problem

This answer may provide hints: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67245228/143475
It should be possible to re-write your assertion to be less memory-intensive. Most teams don't run into this issue.
Also please consider contributing code to improve Karate.
